# Irreducible characters of $\operatorname{GL}_2(F_q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Looking at the character table below of $\operatorname{GL_2}(F_q)$ for some prime power $q$ in Fulton-Harris (Representation Theory, A First Course), there are $\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)$ Cuspidal representations of dimension $q-1$ For which the irreducible character $X_{\varphi}$ is given in the last line of the table. Quoting from the book:

> These $\frac{1}{2}q(q - 1)$ representations, for $\varphi\ne\varphi^q$, and with $X_{\varphi}= X_{\varphi^q}$, therefore complete the list of irreducible representations for $\operatorname{GL_2}(F_q)$ .

[image]

I am missing an explicit description of the $\varphi_i$ maps for $i \in \{1,\dots,\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)\}$ in the characters $X_{\varphi_i}$.

All possible maps $\varphi_i$ are completely determinated by the image of a generator of the cyclic group $\Bbb F_{q^2}^*$, say:

\begin{equation}\label{key}
  \begin{aligned}
  \varphi_i: \Bbb F_{q^2}^* &\to \Bbb C^* \\
   \xi_{q^2-1} &\to (\varepsilon)^i
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}

where $\xi_{q^2-1},\varepsilon$ are primitive $(q^2-1)^{th}$ roots of unity in  $\Bbb F_{q^2}^*$ and $\Bbb C^*$ respectively.

Let's keep only the $\varphi_i$ for which $\varphi\ne\varphi^q$:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  \varphi_i = \varphi_i^q &\Leftrightarrow \forall z=\xi_{q^2-1}^k ,\ \varphi_i(z) = \varphi_i(z^q) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall k\in \{1, \dots, q^2-1\},\  \varepsilon^{ik} = \varepsilon^{ikq} \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall k\in \{1, \dots, q^2-1\},\  1 = \varepsilon^{ik(q-1)}
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}

We can see that for $i \in \{j(q-1)\}_{j\in\{ {1,\dots, q+1}\}}$  gives maps $\varphi_i$ such that $\varphi=\varphi^q$.

We obtained $q^2-1 - (q+1)=q(q-1)$ maps, but we need to restrict more in order to have only $\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)$ irreducible characters $X_{\varphi_i}$. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Coding theorists are using these fields.

Comment: I don't think it  helps to label the homomorphisms $\phi:C_{q^2-1}\to\mathbb{C}^{*}$ by natural numbers $i$ since there's no canonical generator for the cyclic group. What we have are characters labelled by the $q(q-1)=(q^2-1)-(q-1)$  such homomorphisms which don't have $C_{q-1}$ in the kernel; and the pair labelled by $\phi$ and $\hat{\phi}:x\mapsto\phi(x^q)$ coincide, so there are $\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)$ of them (since $\hat{\hat{\phi}}=\phi$).

Comment: Thank you @ancientmathematician, I agree that there is no canonical generator, I just didn't know how to explicitely write the $\varphi$ without "choosing" some generator. I am not familiar with the notation $C_{q-1}$, does it denote the elements of $\Bbb (F_{q^2})^*$ which are a $(q-1)^{th}$ power?

Comment: By the way, I had another question, I think there is a misprint in the above character table for irreducible characters $U_{\alpha}$ and $V_{\alpha}$. In the last column it reads $\alpha(\zeta^q)$, but $\zeta^q \not\in (\Bbb F_{q^2})^*$. Should it rather be $\alpha(\zeta^{q+1})$?

Comment: Sorry by $C_{q^2−1}$ I just meant a generic cyclic group, I should have written the specific (cyclic) group $\mathbb{F}_{q^2-1}^{*}$.

Comment: I don't think it's a misprint. The set of the $d_{x,y}$ can be identified with the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^2-1}=\mathbb{F}_q[t]/\langle t^2-\epsilon\rangle$ see eg https://mspace.lib.umanitoba.ca/bitstream/handle/1993/35256/Kaur_Gurjyot.pdf?sequence=1  page 61 ish

Comment: Nice reference, thank you! Actually I still don't understand why $\alpha$ which is a character of $(\Bbb F_q)^*$ can take $\zeta^q$ as an input, which is not an element of  $(\Bbb F_q)^*$ since $(\zeta^q)^{q-1}\ne 1$. In kaur's thesis, in page 54, the tables of characters $\chi_{U_{\alpha}}$  and $\chi_{V_{\alpha}}$, we see that $\alpha$, which is the restriction of $\phi$ to $(\Bbb F_q)^*$ takes the norm $x^2-\varepsilon y^2$ as an input, which is indeed an element of $(\Bbb F_q)^*$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I now see what you're worried by: earlier you wrote $\zeta^q\notin\mathbb{F}_{q^2-1}^{*}$ but the problem is $\zeta^q\notin\mathbb{F}_{q-1}^{*}$. I think you're right, that unless the book has extended the definition of $\alpha$ in some way, then the norm is needed.

Comment: Thank you @ancientmathematician, indeed you spotted the mistake in my comment, I meant $\zeta^q\notin\mathbb{F}_{q-1}^{*}$.

Comment: Final comment: changed my mind, it's surely a misprint for $\alpha({\zeta^{1+q}})$ which is of course $\alpha$ of the norm.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @ancientmathematician!